# Show that $\sigma$ is an algebra on $[0,1)$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $X=[0,1)$ and
\begin{align*}
\sigma\,=\,\{\varnothing\}\cup\left\{\,\bigcup_{i=1}^m\,[a_i,b_i)\,\bigg|\,m\in\mathbb N,\,a_i,b_i\in[0,1]: \ a_i<b_i\leq a_{i+1}<b_{i+1},\ \forall i\in\overline{1,m}   \right\}.
\end{align*}
I want to show $\sigma$ is an algebra on $[0,1)$.

My proof :

> First, since $X=[0,1)$, $X$ is clearly an element of $\sigma$.

> Next, let $S\in\sigma$. If $S=\varnothing$, we have $X\setminus S=X\in\sigma$. So we consider $S\ne\varnothing$. There exists $m\in\mathbb N,\ a_1,b_1,\cdots,a_m,b_m\in[0,1) $ such that
> \begin{align*}
> a_i<b_i\leq a_{i+1}<b_{i+1} \ \text{ and } \ S\,=\,\bigcup_{i=1}^m\,[a_i,b_i).
> \end{align*}
> Hence
> \begin{align*}
> X\setminus S\,&=\,[0,1)\setminus  \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^m\,[a_i,b_i) \right) 
> \newline &=\,\bigcap_{i=1}^m\,\Big[[0,1)\setminus[a_i,b_i)\Big]
> \newline &=\,\begin{cases}
> [b_1,1) \cap \displaystyle\bigcap_{i=2}^m\,\Big[ [0,a_i) \cup [b_i,1) \Big] &\text{if } a_1=0,
> \\ \displaystyle\bigcap_{i=1}^m\,\Big[ [0,a_i) \cup [b_i,1) \Big] &\text{if } a_1>0
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
> We have
> \begin{align}
> &\Big[[0,a_2) \cup [b_2,1)\Big]\cap\Big[[0,a_3) \cup [b_3,1)\Big]
> \\ =\ \,&\begin{cases}
> [0,a_2)\cup[b_2,a_3)\cup[b_3,1) & \text{if }b_2< a_3,
> \\ 
> [0,a_2)\cup[b_3,1) & \text{if }b_2= a_3.
> \end{cases}
> \\  =:\ \,&\bigcup_{i=1}^n\,[c_i,d_i),
> \end{align}
> Suppose for any $k\in\overline{3,m-1}$, this fact holds
> \begin{align*}
> \bigcap_{i=2}^k\,\Big[ [0,a_i) \cup [b_i,1) \Big]\,=\,\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\,[c_i,d_i)
> \end{align*}
> for some $n\in\mathbb N$. Then we implies
> \begin{align*}
> \bigcap_{i=2}^{k+1}\,\Big[ [0,a_i) \cup [b_i,1) \Big]\,=\,\Big[ [0,a_{k+1} ) \cup [b_{k+1},1) \Big]\cap\, \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\,[c_i,d_i)
> \end{align*}

However, this part here seems not trivial to me. What should I do next ? May you enlight me with some guidance or some hints ? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say this part here seems not trivial to me? What part are you referring to?

Comment: @Nadav I want to show by induction that fact holds for $k+1$.

Answer (score 0):

It would be enough to show that
\begin{align*}
\overline S=X\setminus S &= [0, a_1[\cup [b_m,1[\cup \bigcup_{i=2}^m [b_{i-1}, a_i[
\end{align*}
Note that here $[x,x[$ is assumed to be $\emptyset$, this assumption also helps removing the $\emptyset$ special case from your definition.

In order to prove that, we need, $\overline S\subseteq X$, $S\cap\overline S=\emptyset$ and $S\cup \overline S=X$. The first one is trivially true and the second and third can be visually seen from writing the union as disjoint intervals interleaving sets from $S$ and from $\overline S$ :
\begin{align*}
S\cup \overline S = [0,a_1[\cup [a_1,b_1[\cup[b_1, a_2[\cup [a_2, b_2[\cup\dots\cup [b_{m-1}, a_m[\cup [a_m, b_m[ \cup [b_m, 1[
\end{align*}

It is clear that this union is disjoint from assumptions and that it is $X$.

Comment: what is the symbol $[a,b[ $ ? Is it different from $[a,b]$ ?

Comment: It is the same as $[a,b)$ but I prefer it.